# Bootstrap "buttons-radio" toggle with AngularJS

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I made a small angular module to integrate with the bootstrap "buttons-group" ('s plus a bit of javascript to make them work like radio buttons.  I made it on this module to do the same for checkboxes: http://jsfiddle.net/evaneus/z9rge/

My code is at http://jsfiddle.net/askbjoernhansen/YjMMD/

My questions:

1) Is this the right approach?

2) Will the model be watched three times, or does $scope.$watch() figure out that it's the same model and just do it once? It seems that way.

3) Is it "correct" to muck around with the DOM in the $watch function like I do? It feels "dirty", but I guess that's what I am asking for when I am adding angular to something that's not angularjs compatible natively. Or?

4) Is there a way to put the ng-model attribute on the btn-group instead of on each button? That'd make it appear a lot cleaner.

You can see it at my jsfiddle above, or the code is here, first the html:

```
 <!-- to test the two-way model -->
  <input name="test" type="radio" ng-model="myModel['A']" value="left"> Left<br>
  <input name="test" type="radio" ng-model="myModel['A']" value="middle"> Middle<br>
  <input name="test" type="radio" ng-model="myModel['A']" value="right"> Right<br>


myModel A {{myModel['A']}}<br/>

<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
  <button type="button" buttons-radio=""
    ng-model="myModel['A']" value="left"   class="btn">Left</button>
  <button type="button" buttons-radio=""
    ng-model="myModel['A']" value="middle" class="btn">Middle</button>
  <button type="button" buttons-radio=""
    ng-model="myModel['A']" value="right"  class="btn">Right</button>
</div>
```

And the javascript:

```
angular.module('buttonsRadio', []).directive('buttonsRadio', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function($scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
            element.bind('click', function() {
                $scope.$apply(function(scope) {
                    ctrl.$setViewValue(attr.value);
                });
            });

            // This should just be added once, but is added for each radio input now?
            $scope.$watch(attr.ngModel, function(newValue, oldValue) {
                element.parent(".btn-group").find('button').removeClass("active");
                element.parent(".btn-group")
                .find("button[value='" + newValue + "']").addClass('active');
            });
        }
    };
});​
```

Comment: I was wondering, what exactly is the 4th parameter (Ctrl) of the link function in your directive?

Comment: @Cybrix I think that'd be the angular controller; but I haven't worked with AngularJS for too long to remember. :-)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are invoking the directive three times, once for each button. AFAIK this means the linking function is called three times, binding events and watching for changes. *added a little more on this below.*

It's fine to change the DOM when models change, but what you are doing - *changing classes and values* - can be done automatically by angular using bi-directional data-binding and native directives such as `ng-class`

You can create a directive that renders buttons given a list of options. For example if you have this model and these options

```
$scope.myOptions = ["Left", "Middle", "Right"];
$scope.myModel = "Left"
```

You can create a `buttons-radio` directive like this

```
App.directive('buttonsRadio', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { model: '=', options:'='},
        controller: function($scope){
            $scope.activate = function(option){
                $scope.model = option;
            };      
        },
        template: "<button type='button' class='btn' "+
                    "ng-class='{active: option == model}'"+
                    "ng-repeat='option in options' "+
                    "ng-click='activate(option)'>{{option}} "+
                  "</button>"
    };
});​
```

which can be invoked from your HTML

```
<buttons-radio class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio" 
               model='myModel'    
               options='myOptions'>
</buttons-radio>
```

Things to notice:

1. The template uses an `ng-repeat` directive which goes through all options and compiles buttons accordingly.
2. The directive has its own controller and isolated scope with `model` and `options` to accept bi-directional binding, so angular does its magic when the directive changes their values.
3. If the option matches the current value of the model, then the button is assigned an `active` class.
4. When a button is pressed, the method `activate` (from the directives controller) is called, and it changes the value of the model.

Heres a JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jaimem/A5rvg/4/

---

**EDIT**

I wasn't completely sure about this, but yes, your model will have **three** different watchers, one for every directive invocation. If you are using [Batarang](https://github.com/angular/angularjs-batarang) you can see all the watched expressions from the *Performance* tab and the *AngularJS Properties* panel. Batarang also exposes an `$scope` convenience property, so you can look for your model's watch objects by running the following from the console

```
$scope.$$watchers.filter(function(w){return w.exp ==="myModel['A']"});
```

Comment: Beautiful, thanks jm! It worked with no modifications and was very easy to work with for the tweaks I wanted to make. Also thianks for the Batarang reference, I hadn't seen that before. My old version didn't do the two-way stuff properly in my actual application, your solution does. Awesome, thank you again! I kept the angular.module() syntax; that seems like it's better because I could put this in a reusable module then? Or?

Comment: You are welcome, and yes, keeping related directives into modules makes sense.

Comment: For anybody wrestling with minification, the controller constructor function can be rewritten with the annotated style: `controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) { $scope.activate = function (option) { $scope.model = option; };}]`

Comment: Works nicely, thanks! However, when using Twitter Bootstrap 3, the "active" class is not set. Any insight as to why? Updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/A5rvg/79/

Answer (score 7):

this is simple

```
<html>
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
      <span class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="worktype=1" ng-class="worktype==1?'active':''">
        <input type="radio"   value="1">全职
      </span>
      <span class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="worktype=2" ng-class="worktype==2?'active':''">
        <input type="radio"   value="2">兼职
      </span>
    </div>
</html>
```