# AngularJS - 3-button group acting as radio buttons

Tags: javascript, angularjs, button, radio-button, ionic-framework

Using the [Ionic framework](http://ionicframework.com/), I'm trying to create a group of three buttons that act as radio buttons:

[image: button-group picture]

If I click on Breakfast, I would like Lunch and Dinner to return to their normal (white) state, and Breakfast to turn Blue.

With my current code, I can't get this functionality to work, although I can get the buttons to switch color, slightly randomly (perhaps I just don't understand the `ng-class` directive).

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="bar bar-subheader">
 <div class="button-bar">
   <a class="button" ng-class="{'button-positive' : !isActiveB, 'none': isActiveB}" ng-click="active('breakfast')">Breakfast</a>
   <a class="button" ng-class="{'button-positive' : !isActiveL, 'none': isActiveL}" ng-click="active('lunch')">Lunch</a>
   <a class="button" ng-class="{'button-positive' : !isActiveD, 'none': isActiveD}" ng-click="active('dinner')">Dinner</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

My JS:

```
$scope.active = function(meal) {

 switch (meal) {
   case 'breakfast':
     $scope.$broadcast('slideBox.setSlide', 0);
     $scope.isActiveB = $scope.isActiveB;
     $scope.isActiveL = !$scope.isActiveL;
     $scope.isActiveD = !$scope.isActiveD;
     break;
   case 'lunch':
     $scope.$broadcast('slideBox.setSlide', 1);
     $scope.isActiveB = !$scope.isActiveB;
     $scope.isActiveL = $scope.isActiveL;
     $scope.isActiveD = !$scope.isActiveD;
     break;
   case 'dinner':
     $scope.$broadcast('slideBox.setSlide', 2);
     $scope.isActiveB = !$scope.isActiveB;
     $scope.isActiveL = !$scope.isActiveL;
     $scope.isActiveD = $scope.isActiveD;
     break;
 }
};
```

I can put the code in JSFidle if you require more information and a working solution.

Thanks for your help.

---

NOTE: I would like to maintain my `active()` function, and use the `ng-class` directive if possible, as I have a lot of other code dependent on this function.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/13450409

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Maybe this simplified example will help you a little:

```js
angular.module('plunker', []).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.active = 'breakfast';
    $scope.setActive = function(type) {
        $scope.active = type;
    };
    $scope.isActive = function(type) {
        return type === $scope.active;
    };
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/0.9.26/css/ionic.min.css">
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="bar bar-subheader">
    <div class="button-bar">
        <a class="button" ng-class="{'button-positive': isActive('breakfast')}" ng-click="setActive('breakfast')">Breakfast</a>
        <a class="button" ng-class="{'button-positive': isActive('lunch')}" ng-click="setActive('lunch')">Lunch</a>
        <a class="button" ng-class="{'button-positive': isActive('dinner')}" ng-click="setActive('dinner')">Dinner</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/9HmuTStz70x5KoAvLaP4?p=preview

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you. I knew ng-class was messing me up.

Comment: If we start with twitter bootstrap class this does not seem to work.  Seems best approach is to create your own button class

Answer (score 6):

Here is a more flexible solution for future Googlers.

Working plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/U2Hvx4?p=preview

```
.directive('barSelect',function($parse){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
      model: '=ngModel',
      value: '=barSelect'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl){
      element.addClass('button');
      element.on('click', function(e){
        scope.$apply(function(){
          ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(scope.value);
        });
      });

      scope.$watch('model', function(newVal){
        element.removeClass('active');
        if (newVal === scope.value){
          element.addClass('active');
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

And a usage example:

```
   <div class="button-bar">
     <a bar-select="button.value"
        ng-repeat="button in clientSideList"
        ng-model="data.clientSide"
     >{{button.text}}</a>
   </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I have created a codepen for this that should suit Ionic components. http://codepen.io/niyando/pen/GpEeQR

Answer (score 0):

Here's another alternative approach which combines the other two here. It requires just a single <button-group> element with the following attributes:

- ng-model
- buttons - array of objects containing 'text' and 'value' properties
- button-class - optional string containing CSS class(es) to apply to the rendered links, in addition to the default 'group-btn' and 'group-btn-active' classes

.

```
.directive('buttonGroup',function($parse){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
          model: '=ngModel',
          buttons: '=',
          buttonClass: '='
        },
        template: '<a class="group-btn {{buttonClass}}" ' +
                  '   ng-repeat="button in buttons" ' +
                  '   ng-class="{\'group-btn-active\': isActive(button.value)}" ' +
                  '   ng-click="buttonClicked(button.value)"> ' +
                  '       {{button.text}} ' +
                  '</a>',
        controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.buttonClicked = function(value) {
                $scope.value = value;
            };
            $scope.isActive = function(value) {
                return $scope.value === value;
            };
        }],
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            element.on('click', function(e){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(scope.value);
                });
            });

            scope.$watch('model', function(newVal){
                scope.value = newVal;
            });
        }
    };
})
```

And the example usage:

```
<button-group ng-model="sortOrder" buttons="sortOptions" 
    button-class="'md-button my-other-class'"></button-group>
```

Where sortOptions would be an array of the form:

```
$scope.sortOptions = [
        { value: 'priority', text: 'Priority' },
        { value: 'duration', text: 'Call Duration' }
    ];
```