# Conditionally apply CSS to grouped button bar

Tags: angularjs

What is the best way to conditionally apply CSS to a [grouped button-bar](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#button-bar) in AngularJS?

So far I've tried the following but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
    <div class="item item-divider">
        Rating
    </div>
    <div class="button-bar">
        <a class="button button-clear" ng-class="{ 'energized': isButtonClicked }" ng-click="isButtonClicked = !isButtonClicked">1</a>
        <a class="button button-clear" ng-class="{ 'energized': isButtonClicked }" ng-click="isButtonClicked = !isButtonClicked">2</a>
        <a class="button button-clear" ng-class="{ 'energized': isButtonClicked }" ng-click="isButtonClicked = !isButtonClicked">3</a>
        <a class="button button-clear" ng-class="{ 'energized': isButtonClicked }" ng-click="isButtonClicked = !isButtonClicked">4</a>
        <a class="button button-clear" ng-class="{ 'energized': isButtonClicked }" ng-click="isButtonClicked = !isButtonClicked">5</a>
    </div>
```

The code above produces something like this, as I am working on a rating system, and I only want one number to light up at a time.

[image]

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22258570/angularjs-3-button-group-acting-as-radio-buttons/22258964#22258964

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you are using `$scope` in your controller, you do something like this:

```
$scope.setRate = function (value) {
    $scope.rate = value;
}
```

...and then your view would use that like this:

```
<div class="button-bar">
    <a class="button button-clear" ng-class="{ 'energized': rate == 1 }" ng-click="setRate(1)">1</a>
    <a class="button button-clear" ng-class="{ 'energized': rate == 2 }" ng-click="setRate(2)">2</a>
    <a class="button button-clear" ng-class="{ 'energized': rate == 3 }" ng-click="setRate(3)">3</a>
    <a class="button button-clear" ng-class="{ 'energized': rate == 4 }" ng-click="setRate(4)">4</a>
    <a class="button button-clear" ng-class="{ 'energized': rate == 5 }" ng-click="setRate(5)">5</a>
</div>
```

And come to think of it, I would also use an ng-repeat for this... :-)

https://jsfiddle.net/3f3tc46w/4/

Comment: This is great. How would a solution with ng-repeat look like? Also, does this solution limit the user to one selection rating at a time?

Comment: I've just tested this. It works great. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

One more ngRepeat version:

```js
angular.module('demo', []).controller('DemoController', function($scope) {
  this.selected = 1;
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/0.9.26/css/ionic.min.css">
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="DemoController as demo">
  <div class="item item-divider">Rating</div>
  <div class="button-bar">
    <a class="button button-clear" 
       ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5]" 
       ng-class="{'button-energized': $index + 1 == demo.selected}" 
       ng-click="demo.selected = i">{{i}}</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are keeping only one variable to handle all, therefore all will change together. Keep different variable to track all.

Rating

```
<div class="button-bar">
    <a class="button button-clear" ng-class="{ 'energized': isButtonClicked1 }" ng-click="isButtonClicked1 = !isButtonClicked1">1</a>
    <a class="button button-clear" ng-class="{ 'energized': isButtonClicked2 }" ng-click="isButtonClicked2 = !isButtonClicked2">2</a>
    <a class="button button-clear" ng-class="{ 'energized': isButtonClicked3 }" ng-click="isButtonClicked3 = !isButtonClicked3">3</a>
    <a class="button button-clear" ng-class="{ 'energized': isButtonClicked4 }" ng-click="isButtonClicked4 = !isButtonClicked4">4</a>
    <a class="button button-clear" ng-class="{ 'energized': isButtonClicked5 }" ng-click="isButtonClicked5 = !isButtonClicked5">5</a>
</div>
```

Comment: The user can only have rating selected at a time. With this approach, they can select multiple ratings at a time. For example, they can select 1234 and then 5 at once.

Comment: That is another issue. About applying css one at a time, the above solution will work.